# How to handle a map with pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary

Consider I have a class names People. I'm storing pointers to these people in a map

```
map<string, People*> myMap;
```

To create new People I use the maps [] operator.

```
myMap["dave"]->sayHello();
```

But this gives me a segmentation errors and it doesn't even call the constructor of the People class.

I also tried

```
 myMap.insert( std::make_pair( "dave", new People() ));
```

But that didn't change anything, the Constructor still isn't called and the program shuts down processing this code with an segmentation error.

How do I access and manipulate a map with pointers in them? Why isn't the above working, I get no compile time errors or warnings.

Any insight much appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 12):

Given the map:

```
map<string, People*> myMap;
```

`operator[]` won't create new `People`, it will be creating `People*`, i.e. pointers that don't point to anything.

The simplest solution is to make your map really contain people, not pointers, e.g.:

```
map<string, People> myMap;
```

then the memory management is all handled for you, using `operator[]` will construct new people as needed.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
myMap["dave"] = new People(....);
```

The `new` will call the constructor, return a pointer and insert it into the map.

You need to be careful of memory leaks though. Use smart pointers to over come this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to heap allocate your `People` but use a map, have a look a [Boost Pointer Containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html), specifically the `boost::ptr_map`. It's header only, so you don't need to compile any extra libraries.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_map.hpp>

struct People
{
    int age;
};

typedef boost::ptr_map<std::string,People> PeopleMap;

int main(int,char**)
{
    PeopleMap data;

    data["Alice"].age = 20;
    data["Bob"].age = 30;

    for (PeopleMap::const_iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << "Name: " << it->first << " Age: " << it->second->age << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
People* new_people = new People (member_variable1,member_variable2);

myMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, People*>("key for string",new_people) );
```

or otherwise:

```
People new_people(member_variable1,member_variable2);
myMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, People*>("key for string",&new_people) );
```

Both will work!!!